# Has Tkinter button command disabledbackground been removed in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have read about the command disabledbackground which sets the background colour for a button which is disabled however i get errors as it says it is an unknown option.

Ive impoterd tkinter do i need to import another library?

```
cellbut.config(state="disabled", text="X", disabledbackground="red")
```

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-disabledbackground"
```

Comment: where did you read it? `tkinter.Button` has only `disabledforeground`. `ttk.Button` doesn't have even `disabledforeground`. But it may have it in themes/styles. Doc: [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Answer (score 0):

No, the `Button` widget has never had a `disabledbackground` option.